# Template singleton base class in shared object

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I'm currently porting my project from Windows to Linux.

The project consists of a 'main' shared library, several plugins (also shared libraries) and a launcher application.

Within the 'main' shared library there's a template singleton class another class can inherit from to use the singleton pattern.

The template singleton class is implemented as follows:

```
    template<class T>
    class Singleton
    {
    public:
        static T* getInstance()
        {
          if(!m_Instance)
          {
            m_Instance = new T();
          }

          return m_Instance; 
        }
    private:
        static T* m_Instance;

    protected:
        Singleton()
        {
          assert(!m_Instance);
          m_Instance = (T*)this;
        }

        ~Singleton()
        {
          m_Instance = 0;
        }
    };

template<class T> T* Singleton<T>::m_Instance = 0;
```

A class that inherits from the Singleton class is - for example - the Logger class.
So whenever I call

```
Logger::getInstance()
```

I get a valid instance of the logger class.

For windows this works across multiple DLLs.

If I instantiate the logger in the 'main' dll and try to get the instance in plugin A and B, it'll always return the same instance.

On Linux however I can not reproduce this behavior. For both plugin A and B the assert

```
assert(!m_Instance);
```

triggers and the program stops.

What do I have to do to get the same behavior as I have in Windows with dlls?

I tried linking with -rdynamic but unfortunately this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: A template class of the anti-pattern singleton is totally useless

Comment: Is the condition inside the `getInstance` member function ever going to be true?

Comment: @DieterLücking: Andrei Alexandrescu's classic book "Modern C++ Design" contains some good discussion and code examples. You'll probably find that code in the Loki library.

Comment: @faranwath yes, when calling getInstance without having instantiated the singleton before

Comment: @FelixK. Right, but I like to explicitly instantiate any singletons I may have instead of relying on lazy initialization.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the closest thing you can get that suffices your requirements is something using the [following pattern](http://ideone.com/KdvW5M):

```
#include <iostream>

template<class Derived>
class Singleton {
public:
    static Derived& instance() {
        static Derived theInstance;
        return theInstance;
    }

protected:
    Singleton() {}

private:
    Singleton(const Singleton<Derived>&);
    Singleton<Derived>& operator=(const Singleton<Derived>&);
};
```

---

```
class ASingleton : public Singleton<ASingleton> {
public:
    void foo() { std::cout << "foo() called ..." << std::endl; }
};
```

---

```
int main() {
    ASingleton& a = ASingleton::instance();
    a.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Whatever you want to be accessible through an interface might be injected using multiple inheritance. Though the benefit of using a `Singleton<Derived>` base class is a bit questionable, it just provides that narrow `instance()` implementation.

Comment: The Meyer's singleton has a problem in the OP's case, where it's used for a logger, namely that it might be destroyed already when some global object's destructor ideally should log something. One common solution is the intentionally-never-destroyed dynamically allocated singleton, and I think that's what the OP was aiming for. Another possible solution is the bird-of-Phoenix recreation scheme. However there's another more serious problem here, which is the reason why I deleted my answer, namely access to the singleton from different DLLs. I can easily envison one instance in each DLL. :-(

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Actually different DLLs access only one instance, however when using Unix *.so (shared objects) dynamic libraries this is not the case

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your answer but I'm not asking for a different / better implementation but rather how to build my library that when calling getInstance() from other libraries I'll always get the same instance. Right now I'm getting a new instance for each different library I'm calling getInstance() from. (Only under Linux, though. On Windows getInstance() returns always the same instance, even if I call it from different dynamic libraries.)

Comment: @FelixK. Sorry, seems I have missed that point. I thought you were mainly asking about the correct template pattern. I can't tell, if this implementation solves your problem of multiple instantiation over different `.so` shared libraries. Anyway this way creating the instances is a lot better than using `new()`, and fixes a number of problems.