# C++: Overloading delete on a polymorphic singleton class

Tags: c++, memory-management, singleton, operator-overloading, dynamic-memory-allocation

Suppose I have the following:

```
struct Base {
  virtual ~Base() noexcept = default;
  ...
};

struct Singleton
    : public Base {
  void* operator new(size_t sz) noexcept { return instance(); }
  void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept {
    // the body is supposed to be empty since new() doesn't allocate
    ++delete_count;
  }
  static Singleton* instance() noexcept {
    static Singleton kInstance;
    return &kInstance;
  }
  ...
};
```

(I use such a singleton class to reduce overhead in a polymorphic container-like class, e.g. `std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Base> >`, esp. if multiple of them appear in the container.)

I'm surprised that the following code *crashes*:

```
int delete_count = 0;
Singleton* s = new Singleton;
Singleton* s2 = new Singleton;
assert(s == s2);
assert(s == Singleton::instance());

delete s;
assert(1 == delete_count);
assert(s == Singleton::instance());

delete s2;  // crashes with free(): invalid pointer
assert(2 == delete_count);
```

Interestingly, if I make the `Singleton` class non-polymorphic, i.e. remove the virtual destructor from `Base`, everything works fine (even if I make the `Base` class non-empty by adding class members).

Does anyone have an explanation why this happens and how to fix it?

**Edit**: It seems that changing the `Singleton::delete` to:

```
void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept {
  ::new(ptr) Singleton;  // re-initialize using placement new
  ++delete_count;
}
```

makes it to work, at least on GCC 4.8.1

Comment: Your approach overloading `new()` and `delete`, and stating to have multiple of these _Singletons_ is pretty weird. [That's what I would do.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22998019/template-singleton-base-class-in-shared-object/22998472#22998472)

Comment: Probably also relevant: [How to store a reference of a singleton class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549704/how-to-store-a-reference-of-a-singleton-class/23549834#23549834)

Comment: The question really is whether an overridden operator `delete` in derived classes is recognized by parent classes.  If not, then the program has implementation-defined behavior (maybe UB, but not sure) due to the parent class `Base` invoking its implementation of the default destructor.  Someone with the standard should comment on this.

Answer (score 1):

The code runs fine with both GCC (4.9) and Clang. **GCC 4.8.2 fails.** VC++ 2013 fails as well.

Here is a [minimalistic code example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c261691e2523633).

What compiler (and of course version) are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 flakes out on the `delete s2;`  Seems to be calling the `Base` destructor, which hasn't been overriden.  Caveat -- I had to remove the `noexcept` and `default` specifiers for the code to compile with VS 2013.

Comment: Checked GCC 4.8.2 and it failed.

Comment: gcc 4.8.1 (Ubuntu 4.8.1-2ubuntu1~12.04)

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking **undefined behaviour**. Here's why.

A *delete-expression* always calls the destructor, unless the pointer to be deleted is null. Quoting from §5.3.5/6 of the C++11 standard,

> If the value of the operand of the *delete-expression* is not a null pointer value, the *delete-expression* will
>   invoke the destructor (if any) for the object or the elements of the array being deleted.

This occurs even if the *delete-expression* calls a user-defined *deallocation function* as it does here.

Calling the destructor twice on the same object invokes undefined behaviour if the object has a non-trivial destructor. This is thanks to §12.4/15,

> Once a destructor is invoked for an object, the object no longer exists; the behavior is undefined if the
>    destructor is invoked for an object whose lifetime has ended (3.8)...

and §3.8,

> ... The lifetime of an object of type `T` ends when:
>
> — if `T` is a class type with a non-trivial destructor (12.4), the destructor call starts, or ...

However, if the virtual destructor in the base class is removed, then `Singleton`'s destructor becomes trivial (see §12.4/5). In this case the behaviour is well-defined according to the standard. (In a sense, this is because trivial destructors are no-ops, whereas nontrivial destructors actually modify vptrs and such.)

Comment: Does adding `::new(ptr) Singleton;` to the body of `delete` make the behavior `defined`?

Comment: @leden Yes, I think that makes it well-defined. Don't quote me on that though.

Comment: But it looks like my fix is not thread-safe, is it? E.g. consider a thread using the singleton, while another one calls `delete`...

Comment: @leden That's true. I would really suggest a different design here. I'm not sure you're using `new` and `delete` they're intended to be used. Also, I think that someone reading your code would find it very confusing.

Comment: Since the OP is using C++11, the simple static variable version of the singleton is guaranteed to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is how g++ manage its internal states.

I found that this code compile and run correctly in clang, but fails in gcc. The reason was that, at the first delete, it calls the class defined. But for the second call, it calls for the global ones.

To solve this, I suggest to move allocation and deallocation to the Base class

Comment: Are you saying that this is a bug in GCC or my example is *undefined behavior* (according to the C++ standard)?
I also don't quite understand why second `delete` causes deallocation of the Base class `only if` the class is polymorphic.